# Telerik Openaccess ORM - How to insert a record

Tags: c#, orm, telerik-open-access

In Entity Model generated classes, we had SaveChanges() method. What's equalant function in Telerik ORM?

Comment: I found Telerik OpenORM overly complicated to learn.  I suggest instead you look into SubSonic (http://subsonicproject.com).  Its SUPER easy to use and learn.  If you like LINQ, use Subsonic 3.0.  If you don't like LINQ, use Subsonic 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenAccessContext object (usually called dbContext) has a SaveChanges() method.  See http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/getting-started-root-quickstart-winforms-update-delete.html

Good luck!

-Michael